# Clean Twitter Feed With R in R Studio

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a sentiment analysis of twitter data. I have downloaded the tweets from twitter and done some preprocessing on them. 
A problem arises that when I view the data I see some non-English or non-ASCII characters still present such as

攼㹤愼㸰戼㹣攼㹤戼㹤㤼㹣攼㹤愼㸰戼㹣攼㹤戼㹤㤼㹣攼㹤愼㸰戼㹣攼㹤戼㹤㤼㹣
                       and

How do I remove these characters from the downloaded feed?

Comment: Are you using an R package to download the tweets? Can you give us some example tweets with the characters you want to remove, or some code you've tried already?

Comment: @OliverFrost, I've fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Post your fix as an answer so others can see what you did.